# plt.show adds extra legend labelspacing between rows if there are subscripts, but fig.savefig does not?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I plot a figure and legend using the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create sample data

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y2 = [4, 3, 2, 1]
y3 = [2, 3, 2, 1]

# Create the main figure

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Plot the lines

line1, = ax.plot(x, y1, label='$\\mathdefault{H_{12}\\ 5}$')
line2, = ax.plot(x, y2, label='$\\mathdefault{H_{12}\\ 5}$')
line3, = ax.plot(x, y3, label='$\\mathdefault{H_{12}\\ 5}$')
line3, = ax.plot(x, y3, label='$\\mathdefault{H_{12}\\ 5}$')
line3, = ax.plot(x, y3, label='$\\mathdefault{H_{12}\\ 5}$')
line3, = ax.plot(x, y3, label='$\\mathdefault{H_{12}\\ 5}$')
line3, = ax.plot(x, y3, label='$\\mathdefault{H_{12}\\ 5}$')

# Create a legend for the lines below the figure

fig.legend(loc='lower center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 0), ncol=1, fontsize=8, labelspacing=0.5)

# Set labels and title

ax.set_xlabel('X-axis')
ax.set_ylabel('Y-axis')
ax.set_title('Multiple Lines with Legend Below')

# Adjust layout for better appearance

plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.4)
plt.show()
```

I get different amount of legend labelspacing between the rows of the legend in the popped-up window versus the saved figure. The figure in the screen shotted pop-up window in spyder Automatic backend (left) has more spacing than the figure saved as png (but also with other file formats) using `fig.savefig(filepath,dpi=600, transparent=False,bbox_inches='tight')` (right)
[image]

I overlayed the figures and the font(sizes) are exactly the same. I figured that this issue only shows up when the legend labels have subscripts. It seems that `plt.show()` does generate extra space for subscripts while fig.savefig does not. Is this a bug, or how can I/we fix it. Anyone any ideas to solve this or work around? Any way to let `plt.show()` just ignore the fact that there are subscripts?

Following the comment from @Jody Klimak, my tex related rcParams are:

```
'text.antialiased': True,'text.color': 'black','text.hinting': 'force_autohint','text.hinting_factor': 8,'text.kerning_factor': 0,'text.latex.preamble': '\\usepackage{amsmath}\\usepackage{amssymb} ''\\usepackage{sfmath}','text.usetex': False,'mathtext.bf': 'sans:bold','mathtext.cal': 'cursive','mathtext.default': 'it','mathtext.fallback': 'cm','mathtext.fontset': 'dejavusans','mathtext.it': 'sans:italic','mathtext.rm': 'sans','mathtext.sf': 'sans','mathtext.tt': 'monospace',
```

Comment: I don't think this works for a standard Matplotlib setup.  What rcParams are you using for the TeX commands?

Comment: I do realize that I changed the SHRINK_FACTOR from 0.7 to 0.8 in _mathtext.py, but also when setting that back to 0.7 the issue still persists.

Comment: Yes but this is still not reproducible with a standard set of rcParams so what are your tex related rcParams ?

Comment: Ah! I updated my original post with the tex related rcParams. Maybe it is because of the specific preamble?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with the given rcParams.  Both the plt.show and savefig versions look the same.  Neither look exactly the same as your version, so I assume you are doing something else as well.  Perhaps using inline in a Notebook?

Comment: The issue is maybe that I am using an older matplotlib version, 3.5.2. In terms environment I am using Spyder with automatic backend. But can live with that for now, by just manually calling plt.subplots_adjust() just before saving to at least prevent the large whitespace between legend and axes.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, however this is much more easily accomplished in newer  Matplotlib via 'outside lower center' and `layout='constrained'`.  No need to manually adjust the subplot spacing.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rc = {'text.antialiased': True,'text.color': 'black','text.hinting': 'force_autohint','text.hinting_factor': 8,'text.kerning_factor': 0,'text.latex.preamble': '\\usepackage{amsmath}\\usepackage{amssymb} ''\\usepackage{sfmath}','text.usetex': False,'mathtext.bf': 'sans:bold','mathtext.cal': 'cursive','mathtext.default': 'it','mathtext.fallback': 'cm','mathtext.fontset': 'dejavusans','mathtext.it': 'sans:italic','mathtext.rm': 'sans','mathtext.sf': 'sans','mathtext.tt': 'monospace'}
plt.rcParams.update(rc)

# Create sample data
...
# Create the main figure

fig, ax = plt.subplots(layout='constrained')

# Plot the lines
...
# Create a legend for the lines below the figure

fig.legend(loc='outside lower center', ncol=1, fontsize=8, labelspacing=0.5)

# Set labels and title
...
plt.show()
fig.savefig('Legend.png', dpi=200)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that is really good that the newer matplotlib has this feature, much simpler!